# "I ate at a restaurant… A dessert was delicious." — Is there an explanation of using "a" before "dessert" other than there was more than one dessert?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

The explanation of using "the" (from [a comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/334675/semantics-using-the-definite-vs-indefinite-article-before-singular-generic-nou#comment635318_334688) from one of threads on ell.stackexchange.com):

> I ate at a restaurant yesterday. **The** dessert was delicious_. — Even though the first sentence didn't mention any dessert, it should be clear to the reader that I'm talking about the dessert at that restaurant.

My variant (which, as far as I understand, is correct too):

> I ate at a restaurant yesterday. **A** dessert was delicious_.

I think the only explanation of using "*a*" before "*dessert*" is that there was more than one dessert. Am I right or maybe there are some other explanations of why we can use "*a*" here?

update:
I was told in the comments below that "***a** dessert was delicious*" is incorrect while "*I had **a** delicious dessert*" is correct. Could you tell me please why they differ in the possibility of using "*a*"?

Comment: This is all getting a bit tedious. I bought a book. The chapter on x is interesting. Hmm. Same thing. The a...a thing does not work in your example. I saw a movie yesterday. The scene with the cows was hilarious. Again. I bought a car. The car is black. And again. What is this telling you? :) I bit into an apple and spit it out. The apple was rotten. Are you sensing a pattern?

Comment: I'll point out that while "a dessert was delicious" doesn't work, "I had a delicious dessert" is perfectly fine.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you Why is "_a dessert was delicious_" incorrect, while "_I had a delicious dessert_" is correct?

Comment: @Loviii — “dessert” can be an uncountable noun, meaning the final course of a meal in general, or a countable one, some specific dish or specific category of dish.  An ice-cream sundae is _a_ dessert.  If you say “a dessert was delicious”, the implication is that another dessert was _not_ delicious.

Comment: @MichaelLorton So you find (2) correct while Lambie and Baby don't. I never thought there could be totally different opinions on this sentence.

Comment: @Lovii English is flexible, so you can bend an odd sentence into having meaning (ex: "A dessert was delicious," meaning that there were multiple desserts).  It's possible that someone in the history of modern English has said that sentence in conversation even.  However, it's not a construction that any native speaker would use in normal conversation.  It's just not right, even if you twist the scenario to try to make it so.  Even if you wanted to tell people that you'd tried multiple desserts and one was good, you would likely say, "Only one dessert was delicious," rather than "A dessert."

Comment: @Loviii I think it's because when an indefinite noun is the subject, the statement becomes a lot more generic—a delicious dessert existed at some point in the past? Yeah, I know, I've had one. If you don't convey in some way that you're talking about the dessert _you ate_ at the restaurant, you're not saying much at all.

Comment: I don't even agree with Michael or Jason's edge cases. You can work really hard to make the sentence make sense, but it will never be a natural thing to say without at least one subtle change to contextualize it. "A dessert there was delicious." "One of the desserts was delicious." Even "a dessert was served by pouring molten chocolate on it" (distinctive enough to stand on its own). Anything.

Comment: _The dessert_ implies _the dessert I had at the restaurant as part of my meal_, not some random dessert.

Comment: *A dessert was delicious, unfortunately I didn't have it, and ate the stodgy bitter cheesecake instead.* Not every string of random words is a likely sentence.

Comment: The point I made in my first comment is this: If you have an a/an determiner, things associated with it, following it or a repetition of the thing itself will take *the*.  **I saw *a* movie yesterday. *The* movie was great**. **I went to *a* play last night. *The stage settings* were wonderful**. This is a typical speech and written pattern in English. That is not to say that we can't do this: I went to a play last night. A play is a wonderful thing to see. But then, we are in generality terrain. 2) is discursively incorrect. I'd make this an answer but don't relish dv's from the uninitiated.

Comment: I like to eat at a restaurant on Fridays. I also like to have a dessert on those occaisions. (generality)

Comment: This question should not be closed. It comes up a lot and ELLs need to understand it.

Comment: Although this might distract from the general idea here, I feel the need to point out that in this case, it would be idiomatic to remove the determiner altogether. You could say "I went to a restaurant yesterday. Dessert was delicious." and it would sound natural. Strangely, I cannot think of other examples that work like this. In that two-sentence phrase, you cannot replace "dessert" with any of the following: "food", "entree", "meat", "soup". Does anyone understand this? 

Comment: @the-baby-is-you You gave some examples: "_A dessert there was delicious_.", "_One of the desserts was delicious_." and "_A dessert was served by pouring molten chocolate on it_." But I couldn't understand whether you gave them all as correct or as incorrect. Could you clarify it please?

Comment: @Loviii All correct.

Comment: @partyphysics One can write any number of things. Not all are relevant to the question here. I went to a restaurant yesterday. Dessert (dinner, lunch, tea) was delicious." Most would agree that dessert has an implied "the" there. It is just omitted.

Comment: Of course, all those sentences from the baby-is-you-are correct. But yours are not disjointed. They are linked. And afaic, I'm the only one who addressed that thoroughly.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. Since this has been such a hard slog, I went and got "proof", which says the same thing that I said...

Answer (score 1):

PLEASE NOTE: This answer concerns **two separate utterances following on from each other**: that is the context here. Those are the examples from the OP.

**This is not about whether one can use a/an or the as a determiner in some sentence in English.** Ergo, ngrams ain't going to give us an answer to this.

If you have an **a/an** determiner, *things associated with it, following it or a repetition of the thing itself in the next sentence will take **the**.* when the idea is specific to the experience or situation.

For example:

I saw **a** movie yesterday.  **The** movie was great.
I went to **a** play last night. **The** stage settings were wonderful.

This is **a typical speech and written pattern in English**.

BUT we can also do this:
*I went to **a** play last night. **A** play is a wonderful thing to see.*
OR
*I went to **a** restaurant yesterday. I had **a** wonderful dessert!*

The OP's variant is discursively incorrect. Why? Because you ate at **a** restaurant (generality) and you had **a** dessert (generality) there. So what happens in actual specific utterance is this:

I ate at **a** restaurant yesterday. And **the** dessert was very good.

The dessert is specific to that experience and therfore cannot be "a dessert".

BUT compare that to this:

I ate at **a** restaurant yesterday. And I had **a** delicious dessert.

[two generalities]

For those who need further proof:

> Major Uses of 'the' "In broad outline, the major uses of the are the
> following:
>
> 1. for something previously mentioned: yesterday I read a book . . . the book was about space travel (This is the anaphoric, or 'pointing
>    back,' function of the definite article);

[definite article grammar_The Thought Company](https://www.thoughtco.com/definite-article-grammar-1690423)

Comment: Is this evidence-based?

Comment: Agree that this is subtle, and mostly 'it just sounds wrong'.  You could use 'A dessert' in a well-formed sentence, e.g. "I ate at a restaurant. A dessert was dropped on my head"

Comment: “And **the dessert** was delicious”. I think "a" + adjective + noun is its own thing. Compare "*It was a great play*" and "*The play was great*" in both instances the thing being mentioned is identifiable and the listener understands which play the speaker is referring to. P.S *Not* my downvote even if I may [belong to the  uninitiated!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/347149/i-ate-at-a-restaurant-a-dessert-was-delicious-is-there-an-explanation-of-u#comment674590_347149)

Comment: @JeffUK Yes, I gave an example of what you said.  "I ate at a restaurant yesterday. And I had a delicious dessert.", which is a genarality.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  You are missing my point: The a/an in English in one sentence is usually followed by a "the" thing in the second. Again: "I went to **a** great play. **The** play was so interesting." **Of course**. My point is very specific. *It is not about using a/an **versus the**.* in separate sentences. It is about using a/an **followed by** another sentence semantically linked to it.

Comment: "I went to **a** restaurant. It was very busy. **A kind waiter** guided me to my reserved table.". The original sentence has **a restaurant** followed by **the dessert** NOT **the restaurant**. Maybe *you* are missing my point.

Comment: Then, Mari-Lou A, as I showed there can be **a and a**: I ate at a restaurant yesterday. And I had a delicious dessert. Same idea as a restaurant + a kind waiter. A generality.

Comment: For me as a non-native speaker, this approach with the generality is the closest to what is going on. I have another way of attacking this, by letting go everything before the sentence *A dessert was delicious*, what does it mean: it means that somewhere for someone X was Y - it doesn't imply that a previous sentence should give more clarification. The version with *the* OTOH has this implication, however I can't tell exactly why, but it indicates that there must've been information previously about where and for whom X was Y - and this indication is a must, if that previous information ...

Comment: @DávidLaczkó I am getting tired of saying the same thing over and over. Also, I cannot understand most of your comment at all. The whole point of the question is to **compare** two sets of sentences. How is that not clear? And how is it not clear that that is how I answered the question?

Comment: ... does exist. @Mari-LouA Your example of *A kind waiter guided me to my reserved table.* is quite interesting: I don't think that the part that we need to look at is what you highlighted: it is the part *my reserved table*. Of course there is no *the*, but in some languages, like Hungarian, we would say it *the my*, so there is a kind of implicit *the* in the possessive, and that refers back to a previous sentence, as I explained above. And it can't be changed to *to a reserved table*, because then the meaning wouldn't be consistent, a table can't reserved for someone else just me, ...

Comment: ... so no generality allowed.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Please don't get us sidetracked with Hungarian. It just isn't relevant here.

Comment: OK, I thought I add something from outside the box.

Answer (score -1):

In the example you have given of the two sentences "dessert" is specific (idiomatically so) — hence it takes the definite article — "THE".

Had the waiter asked you "Would you like ***a*** dessert?" that would have been correct — because it would not have been any specific dessert.

When he/she came to collect your empty plate, they may have said "Did you enjoy ***the*** dessert?" — because by then it would have become specific.

Comment: No, this is about a/an **followed by** another sentence. Not whether individual sentences take a/an or the. And even in **your example** where the "the" is separated **in time** from the a/an, it becomes "the dessert" when the waiter **comes back** and asks his question.

Answer (score -2):

Google Ngram confirms the version with the definite article (*the dessert was*) is preferred with the countable usage of *dessert*

[image].

The same is true for most countable nouns

[image]

This is because in stories, novels, recounts, accounts, anecdotes etc. the identity of the thing mentioned is clear to both the speaker and the listener.

The definite article clarifies which dessert and restaurant the speaker is referring to; **the one** (dessert) that was eaten in **the restaurant** which the speaker went to.

Comment: This is not the question. The question concerns *two sentences*, one following another and why the determiner "a" doesn't work in a context like this: **I ate at a restaurant yesterday. A dessert was delicious.** [buzzer]. The context is **two sentences**, not a single sentence. Ergo, ngram does not work for this case. And I believe I gave enough examples of contexts like this in my answer and it surprises me that you didn't understand the point of my answer.

Comment: Misleading use of ngrams. They are only really meaningful if you can be sure the data isn't fragmented and is reasonably clean and balanced when it comes to phrases.

Comment: @Astralbee at least I didn't get the spelling wrong. (I know, typos happen to every one)  However,  the same observation you made are valid for your ngram results.  "For dessert" and "For a dessert" doesn't match the OP's example, and bears little to no relevance to the situation described in the original sentence.

Answer (score -3):

'Desert' can be used as both the name of a group of sweet foods *and* the name of a course in a meal. When it is the former, an article is used; when it is the latter, it usually isn't.

Notice [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20dessert%2Cfor%20a%20dessert&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), which compares "*for dessert*" with "*for **a** dessert*". It shows that it is most common without an article. We would normally say that a particular food item is "for desert" to mean it is being served as that course.

Comment: But isn't the word with one 's' only for dry places?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+dessert%2Cfor+a+dessert&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 which seeems to confirm your idea but...

Comment: comparing "a dessert" with "the dessert" which is the crux of the question we see that the definite article (the) has the upperhand https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+dessert%2C+a+dessert&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: No offense, but I don't think you should be answering this if you can't distinguish desert from dessert.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, it is not about comparing *a* and *the*. It is about *more than one utterance* where the *a* item *becomes* a *the item*. How many times or ways can one (me) say this idea?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Oops, that is embarrassing. But guess what... I corrected the ngram, and the results are the same Even stronger in favour of the point I was making.

Comment: Your point is not in context: The context is **a** followed by **a** versus **a** followed by **the**. The question is not about desserts per se. It's about determiners used in two successive, pragmatically related contexts.

Comment: There's a typo on the first word, in the first line, it should be dessert with a double "s".